# How can I make this code execute the if statement properly

Tags: python, selenium

The below code is supposed to wait click a button after 2 seconds. after two clicks it should wait for 15 seconds before proceeding to click again. However the 15 second wait is not happening. What am I doing wrong?

```
#click follow
    clicked=0
    try:
        Fclick=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Follow"]')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Fclick)
        time.sleep(1)
        inputElement.send_keys(e)
    except Exception:
        driver.back()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/am_batman33/?hl=en")
        clicked +=1
        if clicked == 2:
            clicked = 0
            time.sleep(15)
        else:
            time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Does below answer resolved your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems **`indentation`** issue. if else condition falls under `except` block so until and unless if there is no exception in `try` block, the code won't execute.

Simple solution would be keep your code with same intend as try except block.

```
clicked=0
try:
    Fclick=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Follow"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Fclick)
    time.sleep(1)
    inputElement.send_keys(e)
except Exception:
    driver.back()
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/am_batman33/?hl=en")
    clicked +=1

if clicked == 2:
    clicked = 0
    time.sleep(15)
else:
    time.sleep(2)
```